# Pentaho Analyzer Report prompt value after refresh

Tags: pentaho, prompt, analyzer

I developed a dashboards which have a refresh time of 30 minnutes.
This dashboard uses a prompt which reads its data from SQL query.

In which way is possible to refresh the dashboard maintaining the last selection in the prompt?

EXAMPLE

Initial prompt value [a,b,c,d] -> Default selected value [a];

A user change the selected to [b,c]

Dashboard refresh

Prompt selection reinitialized with [a];

In which way is possible to maintain the selection after the refresh?

Thanks.